# jQuery to Add a New Button with the Same onclick as System Generated Button

Tags: jquery

I have a system generated button that, when clicked, launches an address manager. I need to add a second button using jquery that launches the same address manager.

System Generated Button:

```
<input type="image" name="w1001303$ibtnUpdate" id="w1001303_ibtnUpdate" src="/SiteData/SiteID1/ObjectImages/update-address-2.jpg" alt="Update" onclick=" launchBillToAddressManager('w1001303_pnlAddressManager', 'w1001303_hdnAddressID',  'w1001303_tdAddress', 23361339, null, null,  null, null, 'w1001303_chkSetBillToSameAsShipTo', 0); return false;" style="border-width:0px;" rs_id="1206">
```

My Code:

```
$('#w1001303_ibtnUpdate').before('<div id="newAddButton"  onclick=" launchBillToAddressManager('w1001303_pnlAddressManager', 'w1001303_hdnAddressID',  'w1001303_tdAddress', 23361339, null, null,  null, null, 'w1001303_chkSetBillToSameAsShipTo', 0); return false;"><img src="/SiteData/Images/Buttons/2017/add-new-address.jpg" alt="Add New Address" width="155" height="40" border="0"></div>');
```

Comment: Maybe u can try .clone()

Comment: Your code has a few issues; firstly the button `id` is `w1001303$ibtnUpdate` yet you're selecting `w1001303_ibtnUpdate`. You also have mis-matched single quotes. `clone(true)` would see to be the easiest solution here.

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: w1001303$ibtnUpdate is the name, not the id.

Comment: adding the onclick to the div breaks the code and then the new button doesn't show at all

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked. After adding the div containing the new button I added a call that would click the system generated button when my new div was clicked, effectively launching the address manager.

```
$('#w1001303_ibtnUpdate').before('<div id="newAddButton"><img 
  src="/SiteData/Images/Buttons/2017/add-new-address.jpg" alt="Add New 
  Address" width="155" height="40" border="0"></div>');
$('#newAddButton').click(function(){
  $('#w1001303_ibtnUpdate').click(); 
    return false;
});
```